# Pass dynamic data from to div to another div on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am stuck in a problem and in need of support from you guys.

My problem is I want to pass a php variable(dynamically called through database in loop) to another div on the same page without page refresh

//This is a loop

```
<td><a class="linkright" href="#existingcase?case_id=<?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?></a></td>
```

//The div which should get the above php variable

```
<div class="tabright" id="existingcase">
    <?php 
    $c_id = $_GET['case_id'];
    echo $c_id;
    ?>      
</div>
```

//the javascript code for calling divs on the same page

```
<script>
$(".linkright").click(function(){
    $(".tabright").hide();
    theDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(theDiv).slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

It shows in the url like this `index.php#existingcase?case_id=2012001` but never passes the case id to `#existingcase`. And also `#existingcase` div does not load either but without passing caseid value, `#existingcase` loads.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: you can use javascript. Just get the anchor tag text and assign to `#existingcase`

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/JzAMw/

Comment: I did not understand what you said. I want to capture the case id from the link and pass it to a specific div #existingcase on the same page.

Comment: you are printing that same case_id as a text of anchor tag using `$row_mycases['case_id'];`. you can easily get that text using javascript and you can easily print it in your `#existingcase`div.

Comment: I posted my answer below...

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to print clicked `case_id` in div without page load. To do this, you don't want to pass it using url. you can simply achieve it using `javascript`.

If your `div` id `existingcase` is just change your code like this below.

you are printing that same `case_id` as a text of anchor tag using `$row_mycases['case_id'];`. So, you can easily get that text using javascript and you can easily print it in your `#existingcase`div.

`<td><a class="linkright" href="#existingcase"><?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?></a></td>`

I don't know about your other scripts. in `.linkright` click function place this code like this

```
$(".linkright").click(function(){
    $('#existingcase').text($(this).text()); //if your div id is existingcase it will print your case id. 
});
```

try this code. And let me know the result.

<kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JzAMw/)**</kbd>

**UPDATED:**

To pass client side value to serverside without page reload, you can use `jquery.post()` method.

Place this `PHP` code at the top of your page.

```
<?php     
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $caseid = $_POST['id'];
    return print_r($caseid);
  }
?>
```

`$caseid` will contain currently clicked `case_id` value. So, you can use this `$caseid` wherever you want in this page. If you click on the another case id, it will update with respect to currently clicked `case_id`
replace your `js` with below code,

```
$(".linkright").click(function () {
    $(".tabright").hide();
    theDiv = $(this).attr("href");
    $(theDiv).slideToggle();
    $.post("yourPHPFile.php", {    //use your current php file name instead of "yourPHPFile.php"
        id: $(this).text()
    }, function (caseid) {
        $('#existingcase').text(caseid);
    });
});
```

`id : $(this).text()` means, get the current element `.text()` and assign it to `$_POST` variable name of `id`. It will post to `yourPHPFile.php`. And you can retrieve that value like `$caseid = $_POST['id'];`.

In `function (caseid) {`, caseid contains the value of `$caseid`. So, only in this code, I assigned `$caseid = $_POST['id'];`

By this you can directly print clicked case_id text to your `#exixtingcase` div.

Comment: Actually printed caseid's in the <td> will loop and show all the caseid's from the database. So when I click on a particular caseid, #existingcase div will appear and the present div will disappear. So if I do not provide a div #existingcase in the href then how it will know where to go?

Comment: if you click on each `case_id` it should show that case id in `div`?
see that fiddle demo. consider those `<td>`s are created by your loop. If you click on those case id, it will show those `case_id`s in `existingcase` div.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Just help me out with one thing. How can I store the printed case id in #existingcase in a php variable. Because I want to use the case id for further data retrieving from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Any values after # are not sent to the server.  Since PHP is a server technology you php code will never see the values after #

```
<a class="linkright" href="#existingcase?case_id=<?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?>">
```

try doing

```
<a class="linkright" href="existingcase?case_id=<?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?>">
```

instead and your php code should fill the div.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it says "The requested URL /XXXXXXX/existingcase was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your explanation I think you are making a mistake. You are trying to mix Javascript and PHP with out page refresh. This is not possible through your code as PHP is server side and only works on the server. You can't do `href` within the same page and expect PHP code inside this div to be executed. The PHP code will not be there. You can try "view source" in your browser and check it out.
I think the only way to solve your problem is to make AJAX call using Javascript, get the response and put wherever you want (without refreshing the page)

Hope this helps and excuse my English

EDIT : Here is a working example for making a simple AJAX call using Jquery.
Your table should be some thing like this:

```
<td>
    <a class="linkright" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_mycases['case_id']; ?></a>
</td>
```

You will notice I added "data-id" attribute. We will use this id in our AJAX call. Put this in your JS :

```
// Create Jquery ajax request
$("a.linkright").click( function() {
        $.get("example.php",   // Put your php page here
              { case_id : $(this).attr("data-id") }, // Get data, taken from the a tag
              function(data) {  // Call back function displays the response
                   $(".tabright").html("<p>" + data + "</p>");
          }); // Get 
    }); // click event
}); // Document Ready
```

I tested the code and it is working. You will need to customize it to work for you. If all of this AJAX is new to you I suggest these links for you :

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It would be great if could provide any jquery script for how to capture the data from the loop and then pass it to the specific div #existingcase. Thanks in advance

Comment: @tariq Added some AJAX code, let me know you face any problem